# Is there a way to select or return the selected variable from dropdown in selected via selectInput?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity, selectinput

I am trying to build a function which will select the data variables entered from the file and show the data variables to be selected via the dropdown and to display the variable that is selected currently.

Here, I am able to add file and show the variables of data in the dropdown in the Filter Tab, however I am unable to catch the currently selected variable in the server to apply filter.

Below is the code

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myValue <- reactiveValues()

  # Import Data File 
  observeEvent(input$data_import,{
    if(is.null(input$datafile))
      myValue$data<-NULL
    inFile<-input$datafile
    myValue$data <- rio::import(inFile$datapath) 
   })

  # Render Input DataTable 
    output$show_data <- DT::renderDataTable(
     myValue$data, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
   )

    #Functions 

  shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    inputs
  }

  SingleshinyInput <- function(FUN, i, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(i)
        inputs <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
        inputs
  }


  #Display Dynamic Input Filter table
  observe({
  if(is.null(myValue$data))
    return()

    Names <- colnames(myValue$data)
    myValue$Filter  = data.frame(
                                  Logic = c(NA,shinyInput(selectInput, 4, 'logic_', label = "", choices = c("And","Or"))),
                                  Variable = shinyInput(selectInput, 5, 'var_', label = "", choices = Names ),
                                  Filter = shinyInput(actionButton, 5, 'go_button_', label = "Filter", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
                                  Remove = shinyInput(actionButton, 5, 'remove_button_', "", icon = icon("close"), onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_remove_button\",  this.id)' ),

                                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                  row.names = 1:5
                                  )


      }
      )

  #Add new Filter Row 

  observeEvent(input$addnewRow,{
        if(is.null(myValue$Filter))
          return()
          i <- as.character(max(as.numeric(row.names(myValue$Filter)))+1)      
          newRow <- data.frame(Logic = SingleshinyInput(selectInput, i, 'logic_', label = "", choices = c("And","Or")),
                             Variable = SingleshinyInput(selectInput, i, 'var_', label = "", choices = Names ),
                             Filter = SingleshinyInput(actionButton, i, 'go_button_', label = "Filter", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
                             Remove = SingleshinyInput(actionButton, i, 'remove_button_', "", icon = icon("close"), onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_remove_button\",  this.id)' ),

                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                             row.names = i)
        myValue$Filter <- rbind(myValue$Filter,newRow)

      })

  # Render Filter Data Table
   output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
    myValue$Filter, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
   )


  # Remove filter Row  
  observeEvent(input$select_remove_button,{
    if(is.null(myValue$Filter))
      return()
    rowToRemove<-unlist(strsplit(input$select_remove_button,"_"))
    rowToRemove<-rowToRemove[length(rowToRemove)]
    rowToRemove<-which(row.names(myValue$Filter)==rowToRemove)
    myValue$Filter<-myValue$Filter[-rowToRemove,]
    if(!is.na(myValue$Filter$Logic[1]))
      myValue$Filter$Logic[1]<-NA
  })

  # Display bsModal for filter 
  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    toggleModal(session,"CustomDataFilter",toggle="open")


  })


  # Select the variable value selected in the select Input 
  output$FilterDataSettings <- renderUI({
    selected<-unlist(strsplit(input$select_button,"_"))
    selected<-as.numeric(selected[length(selected)])

    Names <- colnames(myValue$data)

    selected_var<-Names[selected]
    print(selected_var)
    selected<-as.numeric(selected)

    print(input[[paste0("var_",selected)]])




    return(NULL)


  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    selected<-unlist(strsplit(input$select_button,"_"))
    selected<-as.numeric(selected[length(selected)])
    paste("You chose", input[[paste0("var_",selected)]])
    print(input[[paste0("var_",selected)]])
  })



  # Show Table Dimensions 
  output$showDataDimensions.FilterData <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(myValue$data)){

      return(paste("The data is not selected "))
    }
      Dim<-dim(myValue$data)
      paste("Dimensions", Dim[1], "X" , Dim[2])

  })
}
```

ui.r

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(



    tags$button(
    id = "reset_button",
    class="btn action-button",
    icon("close")
  ),


  bsModal("CustomDataFilter","Settings","go_CustomDataFilter_Settings",size="small",

       # radioButtons("Less_Than_Greater_Than","Less Than or Greater Than",choices=c("Less Than","Greater Than"),selected="Less Than",inline = TRUE),
        uiOutput("FilterDataSettings"),
        textOutput("result")


  ),



  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", 
             titlePanel("Custom Data Filter"),

             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('datafile', h4('Import File'),
                           accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
                 actionButton("data_import","Import") 

               ),


               mainPanel(

                 DT::dataTableOutput("show_data")

               )

             )

    ), 
    tabPanel("Filter", 
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 uiOutput("showDataDimensions.FilterData")

               ),


               mainPanel(


                 DT::dataTableOutput("data"), 
                 actionButton("addnewRow"," Add New Filter "),
                 actionButton("applyFilter"," Apply Filter to Data ")

               )
             )
    )
  )
)
)
```

Thank you for going through the code and appreciate your response.

Comment: You are quite close to getting this to work, and your example above ^^ is actually reproducible.This sort of thing is far easier to do with shiny modules (I hope to have time and paste an example).